# How do I reverse the URL for an admin action?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm posting this because I searched stackoverflow and docs for a long time without finding an answer -- hopefully this helps somebody out.

The question is, for testing purposes, how do I find the URL that's related to admin actions for a specific model?

Admin model urls can all be found by `reverse(admin:appname_modelname_*)`, where * is the action (change, delete, etc). But I couldn't find one for the admin actions, and since I was defining custom actions, I'd like to get the url.

Answer (score 1):

This took a fair bit of digging, I couldn't find anything in the Django docs about it and I ended up having to inspect the source code of a third party library.

Essentially there are 2 URL patterns, one for bulk actions and one for object actions:

- Bulk: `r'admin/<app_label>/<model_name>/actions/(?P<tool>\\w+)/$'`
- Object: `r'admin/<app_label>/<model_name>/(?P<pk>.+)/actions/(?P<tool>\\w+)/$'`

The URL name pattern is `<app_label>_<model_name>_actions`

Therefore we can **reverse the bulk view**:

- Using args: `reverse("admin:<app_label>_<model_name>_actions", args=["foo"])`
- Using kwargs: `reverse("admin:<app_label>_<model_name>_actions", kwargs={"tool": "foo"})`

and **reverse the object view:**

- Using args: `reverse("admin:<app_label>_<model_name>_actions", args=[1, "foo"])`
- Using kwargs: `reverse("admin:<app_label>_<model_name>_actions", kwargs={"pk": 1, "tool": "foo"})`

Answer (score 1):

The URL for all custom actions is `reverse(admin:<appname>_<modelname>_changelist)`, but the action name is specified in the `action` field of the POST data.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, which is hard to find, is that actions are referenced by `reverse(admin:appname_modelname_changelist)`